# Regex replacing dates in proper order

Tags: c#, regex

So I need to fix a file where the dates were of the form mm/dd/yyyy and the dates needed to be, for the SSIS package to handle it, in the form mmddyyyy (so 03/11/2020 to 03112020).  SSIS then has a component that turns the string into mm-dd-yyyy that SQL understands (I didn't design the package, I just have to work with it as it is)

The file is a CSV file, gets loaded by SSIS into a SQL server database.

To fix the file, I thought to use Regex

```
        private static readonly string basePath = @"C:\Desktop\errorfiles\";
        private static readonly Regex dateMatcher = new Regex(@"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] paths = {
                "file1.csv",
                "file2.csv",
                "file3.csv"
            };
            foreach(string path in paths)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(basePath + path))
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(basePath + @"final\" + path))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var matches = dateMatcher.Matches(line);
                        foreach (Match match in matches)
                        {
                            var dateParts = match.Value.Split('/');
                            string dateStr = String.Empty;
                            foreach (string part in dateParts)
                            {
                                dateStr += part;
                            }
                            line = dateMatcher.Replace(line, dateStr, 1, match.Index);
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My first attempt was with `dateMatcher.Replace(line, dateStr)`, which looked okay until I inspected more closely in the new file and saw the dates were out of order when compared to the original file.  So I tried this route where it'd replace only at the point where the match was found, which brought up another problem.  In cases where the date was the same, it only replaced it in one spot.

So for example:

name,from-date-of-service,thru-date-of-service,date-of-birth

bob,03/11/2020,03/11/2020,07/02/1987

would become

bob,03112020,03/11/2020,07021987

But I'd want *both* to become `03112020` and if I change the `count` parameter in `dateMatcher.Replace` to `-1` it replaces EVERY date on the line like:

bob,03112020,03112020,03112020

Which is also wrong, because the date-of-birth column changes value, and that'd be undesired.

Is there a way to specifically replace each date matching the regex in only the spot where it appears AND also replace where there are values that are the same date?  I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, it's not easy to put into a question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
string line = "bob,03/11/2020,03/11/2020,07/02/1987";
Regex dateMatcher = new Regex(@"(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})");
var newLine = dateMatcher.Replace(line,"$1$2$3");
```

Outputs:

```
bob,03112020,03112020,07021987
```

Explanation:
The search pattern is storing each part of the date in a group, from 1 to 3. Then, the replacement string is taking only those groups

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replace the forward slashes between the month and day and the day and year with empty strings. The following regex can be used to match those forward slashes:

```
(?<=\d{2})\/(?=\d{2}\/\d{4})|(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2})\/(?=\d{4})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZB5XkQ/3/)

This regex performs the following matches.

```
(?<=\d{2})        # match two digits in a pos lookbehind
\/                # match '/'
(?=\d{2}\/\d{4})  # match 2 digits, '/', 4 digits in a pos lookahead
|                 # or
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}) # match 2 digits, '/', 2 digits in a pos lookbehind
\/                # match '/'
(?=\d{4})         match 4 digits in a pos lookahead
```